# Search if Super Table Field Has Rows

Tags: entries, search, filter, plugin-supertable

I have a section with a super table field, and I only want to display entries in that section if the super table field has rows (so basically a "not empty" search). How do I do this? I tried using the `*` and the `:notempty:` search parameters but neither worked.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
  section: 'mySection',
  superTableField: ':notempty:'
}).all %}
```